# Missing / misnamed fields in PostgreSQL table join in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgresql, attribute-joins

First, I'm brand new to PostgreSQL and PostGIS, so my question is probably asked wrong, and it may be a duplicate – but my search attempts didn't find anything. Also, I don't expect this is an issue with the data_ ¯_(ツ)_/¯ _but, for reproduction reasons, the tables are the 2020 and 2019 CSVs from [Boston's property assessment](https://data.boston.gov/dataset/property-assessment).

**Problem:** When I join two tables with matching field names in the QGIS DB Manager, only one set of fields appear; when I rename the fields, the wrong fields are renamed. When I run the same commands in a pgAdmin window, these problems don't happen.

**What I did & what happened**

I tried joining two tables in the QGIS DB Manager

```
SELECT
    a.pid, a.owner, b.pid, b.owner
FROM 
    properties_20 AS a 
        INNER JOIN properties_19 AS b ON a.pid = b.pid
LIMIT 3;
```

Resulting view:

```
pid         owner
0502309029  LADAKH REALTY LLC MASS LLC
0502309031  ROGERS ALEX A
0502309032  CLAIRE A WALTON 2012
```

The resulting view only had two fields: `pid` and `owner`. I expected four: a `pid` for each table and an `owner` for each table. As I'm new to all of this, though, I thought it might be a matter of matching field names, so I renamed the `owner` fields with `AS`.

```
SELECT
    a.pid, a.owner AS owner_20, b.pid, b.owner AS owner_19
FROM 
    properties_20 AS a 
        INNER JOIN properties_19 AS b ON a.pid = b.pid
LIMIT 3;
```

The resulting view added a third column named owner_19, but the column's contents were the table's pid values:

```
pid         owner_20                     owner_19
0502309029  LADAKH REALTY LLC MASS LLC   0502309029
0502309031  ROGERS ALEX A                0502309031
0502309032  CLAIRE A WALTON 2012         0502309032
```

I then tested the same commands outside of QGIS, using pgAdmin 4:

First query (no renaming)

```
pid             owner                           pid             owner
"0502309029"    "LADAKH REALTY LLC MASS LLC"    "0502309029"    "LADAKH REALTY LLC"
"0502309031"    "ROGERS ALEX A"                 "0502309031"    "ROGERS ALEX A"
"0502309032"    "CLAIRE A WALTON 2012"          "0502309032"    "CLAIRE A WALTON 2012"
```

Second query (renaming)

```
pid             owner_20                        pid             owner_19
"0502309029"    "LADAKH REALTY LLC MASS LLC"    "0502309029"    "LADAKH REALTY LLC"
"0502309031"    "ROGERS ALEX A"                 "0502309031"    "ROGERS ALEX A"
"0502309032"    "CLAIRE A WALTON 2012"          "0502309032"    "CLAIRE A WALTON 2012"
```

**Primary question:** Why is this happening? Is there a way I can fix this so it works in QGIS? Is my syntax somehow lazy?

**Secondary question:** If I should just be working in the pgAdmin window, how do load the results as a new layer in QGIS?

I considered posting this on the StackOverflow site, but because the problem is specific to QGIS I asked here.

Answer (score 2):

If you treat each cursor SQL statement as if it were the query after the `AS` in a `CREATE VIEW` directive, then you won't give the cursor an excuse for mangling the column identities.

In fact, you can use `CREATE VIEW` to debug the problem:

```
CREATE VIEW xx_cursor_check AS
SELECT
    a.pid, a.owner AS owner_20, b.pid, b.owner AS owner_19
FROM 
    properties_20 AS a 
INNER JOIN properties_19 AS b ON a.pid = b.pid
LIMIT 3;
```

```
ERROR:   column "pid" specified more than once
SQL state: 42701
```

Then, if you alias all column names to be unique:

```
CREATE VIEW xx_cursor_check AS
SELECT
    a.pid pid_20, a.owner owner_20, b.pid pid_19, b.owner owner_19
FROM 
    properties_20 a 
INNER JOIN 
    properties_19 b ON a.pid = b.pid
LIMIT 3;
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS xx_cursor_check;
```

```
DROP VIEW

Query returned successfully in 76 msec.
```

The key here is to always make sure your queries have unique aliases across the return cursor.

Notes:

1. Since this isn't an OUTER JOIN, you really don't need to list `pid` twice
2. If you try the incompletely aliased query from an ArcMap 10.7.1 Make Query Table, it will eventually fail with the same "42701" error.